# Matlab: in a matrix A, how to find the values of the fourth line, corresponding to some values on the first line?

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
    17     2     4    14    14    16
    19     6    20     9     1    15
A =  3    11    20    19    17     8
    19    20    10    16    19    14
    13    20    17    20    14     4
```

how to find the values ​​of the fourth line, corresponding to 2 and 14 on the first line?

the desired result: `[20 16 19]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to generate a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
result = A(4, ismember(A(1,:), [2 14]));
```

To select values based on two lines:

```
result = A(4, ismember(A(1,:), [2 14]) & ismember(A(2,:), [6 9]));
```

Comment: how will be the result, if the question is: how to find the values ​​of the fourth line, corresponding to 2 and 14 on the first line, and 6 and 9 on the second line?

Comment: See edit. I'm assuming you mean "logical and". If you mean "logical or" between lines 1 and 2, just replace `&` by `|`

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to find the entries in the first line that equal `2` or `14`

```
>> eqTo = [2;14];
>> sel = any( bsxfun( @eq, A(1,:), eqTo ), 1 )

 0     1     0     1     1     0
```

Now you use the logical indices to extract the corresponding entries from the fourth row

```
>> A( 4, sel )

 20    16    19
```